# How does the protobuff compiler distinguish between different services and their messages with same identifiers/tags?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, grpc, grpc-java

The question is regarding the deserialization process. I thought the first bytes describe the tag and the corresponding on-wiretyp. But what if two services using in their messages the same tag/identifier and datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuf actually doesn't distinguish between the two!  Consider the following two messages:

```
message Foo {
  int32 foo = 5; 
}

message Bar {
  int32 bar = 5; 
}
```

Both of these messages will appear to be exactly the same.  The reason is that the message doesn't carry the *schema* along with it.  This makes the messages more compact and faster to process, with the minor downside of possibly being misinterpreted.

If you are using gRPC, the messages may appear the same, but they can be distinguished by which service they are sent to.  For example:

```
service MyService {
  rpc EatTheFoo(Foo) returns (Bar); 
}
service YourService {
  rpc GoToTheBar(Bar) returns (foo);
}
```

Even though both services take and receive messages that appear to be the same, gRPC will include the name of the service and message when sending the message.  Under the hood, it will turn into an HTTP/2 request that looks like:

`POST /MyService/EatTheFoo HTTP/2`

which is then followed by the `Foo` message.  If someone accidentally tried to send a `Bar` message, the server would see that the method name was wrong and reject the RPC.  Thus, the chance of being misinterpreted is pretty small.

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains it very well.